# How to translate cURL to Python requests language?

Tags: python, curl, amazon-s3, python-requests

I have some difficulty in translating cURL options into Python requests for uploading a file to a cloud server Picloud. Based on their description, the first step is to POST a request to make a new file to PiCloud to create a ticket for this upload. The second step is to send instructions extracted from this ticket to upload the file.

I am OK with the first step. But have questions about the second one.

1st step, create a upload ticket.

cURL statement:

```
$ curl -k -u 'key:secret_key' -X POST https://api.picloud.com/file/new/ -d name=file_name
```

My requests code:

```
r = requests.post('https://api.picloud.com/file/new/',auth=(api_key,api_secretkey), verify=False, data={'name':'file_name'})
```

The ticket looks like:

```
{"ticket": {"AWSAccessKeyId": "AKIAJCY7JV52WD4MJSNQ", 
"success_action_redirect": "https://api.picloud.com/file/uploaded/3303/4600939/4a6317595a03f85fbbe9102b2454119dc35d3969/", 
"acl": "private", 
"key": "44ec7b76cb3e046986e82b3f13b2da30208d43a5/your_file_name", 
"signature": "TzFhvowtJnBm2+HCvTSlZkBxM5w=", 
"policy": "eyJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogW3siYnVja2V0IjogInBpLXVzZXItZmlsZXMifSwgeyJrZXkiOiAiNDRlYzdiNzZjYjNlMDQ2OTg2ZTgyYjNmMTNiMmRhMzAyMDhkNDNhNS95b3VyX2ZpbGVfbmFtZSJ9LCB7ImFjbCI6ICJwcml2YXRlIn0sIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkucGljbG91ZC5jb20vZmlsZS91cGxvYWRlZC8zMzAzLzQ2MDA5MzkvNGE2MzE3NTk1YTAzZjg1ZmJiZTkxMDJiMjQ1NDExOWRjMzVkMzk2OS8ifSwgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgIiJdXSwgImV4cGlyYXRpb24iOiAiMjAxMi0wNS0xMVQwMTo1MDo0NFoifQ==",
"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}, 
"params": {"action": "https://pi-user-files.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/"}}
```

2nd step, upload the file.

Basically, I do not quite understand in translating `cURL -L` and `-F` options. Based on instructions from cURL, -L means redirect, and -F means fill in as form.

cURL statement:

```
$ curl -L "https:/.s3.amazonaws.com/" -F "AWSAccessKeyId=1"  -F "success_action_redirect=https://api.picloud.com/file/uploaded/1234" -F "acl=info" -F "key=info"  -F "signature=info" -F "policy=info" -F content-type="info" -F file=your_file_to_upload
```

My bad trial:

```
up_d={"AWSAccessKeyId": "AKIAJCY7JV52WD4MJSNQ", "success_action_redirect": "https://api.picloud.com/file/uploaded/3303/4596631/28ec3c3898bec2523759e15cd62fb39fa62b5c53/", 
      "acl": "private", "key": "44ec7b76cb3e046986e82b3f13b2da30208d43a5/your_file_name", "signature": "BLsaltt+Ohua4tPPISr2eV2Tr8c=", 
      "policy": "eyJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogW3siYnVja2V0IjogInBpLXVzZXItZmlsZXMifSwgeyJrZXkiOiAiNDRlYzdiNzZjYjNlMDQ2OTg2ZTgyYjNmMTNiMmRhMzAyMDhkNDNhNS95b3VyX2ZpbGVfbmFtZSJ9LCB7ImFjbCI6ICJwcml2YXRlIn0sIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkucGljbG91ZC5jb20vZmlsZS91cGxvYWRlZC8zMzAzLzQ1OTY2MzEvMjhlYzNjMzg5OGJlYzI1MjM3NTllMTVjZDYyZmIzOWZhNjJiNWM1My8ifSwgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgIiJdXSwgImV4cGlyYXRpb24iOiAiMjAxMi0wNS0xMVQwMDozOTo0OFoifQ==", 
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream", "file":"new  2.txt"}
    k1=requests.post('https://pi-user-files-test.s3.amazonaws.com/', data=up_d)
```

The error message is

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Conflicting query string parameters: acl, policy</Message><ArgumentValue>acl</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>ResourceType</ArgumentName><RequestId>4767425F264FB0CA</RequestId><HostId>K/pAE6BXLJaRRo56ETWw2uYZed8GR+1+VPPU3TI0pZGNyrqz/PAWSzuwtIAHz9eE</HostId></Error>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the ticket you posted really an actual live response?  And are you actually sending the string literal "info" as the data for those elements?  That looks like some copy pasted documentation text.  I found some S3 docs that suggest, for example, that acl should be one of private, public-read, public-read-write, or authenticated-read.  That would likely explain that error you got, in the least.

Comment: Now try replacing the values in the request body with the values you got in the ticket.  Note that to make this work in the long term, you need to make this dynamic, so it will get a ticket, pull the values from the ticket, then make the second request with the values received in the ticket.

Comment: @sr2222, the errors I have posted are the ones with the replacements. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think now you are in to the specifics of Picloud/your implementation, and I don't know that much about either, nor is the documentation easily Googlable.  If you can track down info on what that error means, I might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't need params or AWSAccessKeyID in the body.  Also, it seems odd to me that they are telling you to jam Content-Type in the body instead of setting it in the header... in any case, you'll also need to set headers in your request.  As per the curl docs, -F sets Content-Type in the header to  multipart/form-data, so you should be doing that in Python too.